# How can I assign to dynamic variable names in a loop?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I want create 10 objects in a loop and assign them to variables.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    Cat i = new Cat();
}
```

How can I create a variable name dynamically?

Comment: This is the kind of thing arrays or maps are for.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might be the solution you are looking for,

```
ArrayList<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++){
    catList.add(new Cat());
}

// In order to retrieve items,

// catList.get(0) -> Object first inserted.
// catList.get(1) -> Object second inserted.....
```

Comment: That will create 11 objects, not 10.

Comment: That is what OP is using in his loop. But I guess I missed the part where he said he wants to create 10 objects, it thought it was for java 10. I will update my answer. Thanks